# powershell eairliest email, calendar, contact

Tags: powershell, exchange-server, powerquery, powershell-3.0

I was hoping someone can help me with the following.  I found this script that can give you the earliest item, but I would like to find out the earliest type: email, calendar, or contact.  Sometimes, we get requests regarding the earliest EMAIL.
Is this doable?
Thank you

```
Get-MailboxFolderStatistics -IncludeOldestAndNewestItems -Identity USERNAME | 
    Where OldestItemReceivedDate -ne $null | 
    Sort OldestItemReceivedDate | 
    Select -First 1 OldestItemReceivedDate
```

Answer (score 0):

Try appending `containerclass` to the end of `OldestItemReceivedDate` and changing the `1` to say `10` then use this ["Item type and message classes"](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/outlook/concepts/forms/item-types-and-message-classes) to figure out what you Message Class you have. This is a very quick and dirty one liner. If you need to pretty this up, you can dump the first 10/20/30 (whatever number you think will trap the first 'email') items and then parse through for the first instance of IPM.Note (email).

Comment: it looks like my oldest (Eairlest) email is located in Purge.. but PowerShell containerclass is blank...